# Fetch API in React for JSON file: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, java, json, reactjs, fetch

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to parse a JSON file available on a URL.

This is the code I'm using:

```
let link = 'https://Company-url/file.json';
fetch(link, {
          method: "GET",
        }).then(resp => resp.json())
      .then((data) => {
        functionName.setData(data);
      });
```

The file is directly (publically) accessible by its URL.

I read other answers and tried giving content type as JSON in the header but it is still showing the same.

In the chrome network tab, I'm able to view the file being fetched and checked with the JSON lint, if the syntax of JSON was valid. It was showing valid.

Not able to figure out what am I missing here.

This is the JAVA code I'm using to generate the JSON file:

```
File jsFil = new File(i18nGuestPayResourceFolder + File.separator+outputFileName);
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(jsFil), "UTF-16");
out.write(msgContainr.getMesageKeyValueJson());
```

Comment: UTF-8 with BOM?

Comment: And what does come in the response?, use resp.text instead of resp.json to check what is it contents. put the resp.text in a console.log aswell

Comment: sounds like you do not have valid JSON

Comment: I'm generating the file with UTF-16 encoding via JAVA. Added code for the same. @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: @epascarello I checked with JSON lint. It shows valid JSON. It's a simple key pair JSON.
@C

Comment: @Csharls In console.log it gives �� followed by the JSON

Comment: maybe it's an encoding problem? what is the http header of content-encoding?

Comment: Can you open the file with an hexadecimal editor? If you don't have one at hand, you can use [hexed.it](https://hexed.it). Upload the raw file, if you copy and past you may lose encoding changes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments here, I changed my JAVA code to below so that JSON is generated with UTF-8 encoding.

```
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(jsFil), "UTF-16");
```

Now my files are being read from the API.

I got to know it happens because default encoding is assumed to be UTF-8 on webpages.

Comment: In fact, UTF-8 is the only encoding allowed in JSON ([source](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.html#section-8.1)). You could tweak your `Content-Type` header to declare UTF-16 but JSON implementations are likely to fail.